# Bash override $0 - the name of the script

Tags: bash, symlink

There is a busybox-like shell script that decides what to do depending on from which symlink it is called.

I'd like to call it directly and pass the name of symlink without actually creating a symlink.

Comment: What is wrong with creating symlinks?

Comment: Imagine multiple symlinks pointing to that script: a->s, b->s, c->s. Now I need s to do a1 when it is called through a, b1 when through b, etc. The way to do that is point a, b, c to some script that does the transformation of the name and calls s. Currently, there are 3 utilities (abc) and 3 modes.

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a script and if it's ok to be sourced:

```
bash -c '. script.sh' overridden-name param1 param2
```

Works for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Though the idea would have never crossed my mind, I gave it a try for fun.
My conclusion: you can't (at least, *I* couldn't).

Here's how and why, pretending you'd use $1 as the would-be symlink.

```
#!/bin/bash

# not surprisingly, you cannot do this:
# 0 = $1
# '0' is not a valid variable name, so bash try to use it as a command, hence:
# 0: command not found

# you CAN do this, as meaningless as it seem:
# $0 = $1
# but say your script is called as ./foobar.sh, this will actually result in:
# ./foobar.sh = whatever_$1_is
# ...which is a nice fork bomb, since you'll call your script again,
# which will call your script again,
# which will call your script again,
# which will call ...etc etc etc
# Try it! :-)

# I've just learned about $BASH_SOURCE from here:
# http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/debugging.html#BASHSOURCEREF
echo BASH_SOURCE $BASH_SOURCE
# you CAN do this:
BASH_SOURCE = $1
# ...but to no use, since the following will show that BASH_SOURCE
# rightfuly behave as read-only:
echo BASH_SOURCE $BASH_SOURCE #unmodified
```

So if your idea is to prototype a "a la busybox" behavior without bothering creating the symlinks, I'd suggest:

```
#!/bin/bash
called_as = $1 # to be replaced with called_as = $0 once you're done prototyping
# if called_as such name do this
# if called_as such other name do that
```

Comment: I'd not mess with the parameters. It should be very transparent for the program because among other things it's made to seamlessly trace parameters and stdin/stdout. I'll post an exact problem (so the solution for that may be simpler than simulating symlinks).

Comment: @Velkan "I'd not mess with the parameters" me neither, that what I said this idea would've never cross my mind. I'm familiar with busybox symlink trick, maybe this led me to misunderstood you're question in the first place? Isn't what your trying to do something like: [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/basic.html#HELLOL)